# Laravel on Google App Engine Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine

I'm deploying my laravel web on google app engine but it keeps showing the `Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found` error. Here's what i've done :

1. move `facade/ignition` from `require -dev` to `require`
2. move `nunomaduro/collision` as well
3. all sorts of cache clearing `php artisan` commands
4. deleting composer.lock and vendor folder then run `composer install`

none of the above seems to work.

Problem : GAE showing `Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found`

Expected output : login page to the website

Query : what else can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: just did and still no changes

Answer (score 1):

try

```sh
composer remove --dev facade/ignition
```

as it is only need in development mode

Comment: i did remove it, then ```nunomaduro/collision``` error comes out, so i moved that too but the error is presistent

Answer (score 0):

i reliaze that there is a problem updating vendor when you install or change composer dependencies. Try to create a new project and deploy again with "nunomaduro/collision" in require. I didn´t find other solution.